# how to remove a child and center after that

Tags: actionscript-3

Im struggling with a problem and dont know how to solve it.
I want every time i click the mouse the cards to be 1 less from the previous time, and at the same time to center the new (in my case when i click ill have -> 3 cards) again on the stage.

but i can only think of doing this by pushing the newly created cards in a Sprite but dont know how to remove the last card after that.
i did try just **myArray[lastElement]** but it gives me

**ArgumentError: Error #2025: The supplied DisplayObject must be a child of the caller.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at MainClass/onClick()**

**CardClass** is representing a simple picture of a card

so i have this code so far:

```
    public class MainClass extends MovieClip
{

    private var myArray:Array = new Array();
    private var myContainer:Sprite = new Sprite();

    public function MainClass()
    {
        for (var i:int=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            myArray[i]= new CardClass();
            myArray[i].x = myArray[i].width * i + i * 10;
            myContainer.addChild(myArray[i]);
        }

        myContainer.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - myContainer.width / 2;
        myContainer.y = 40;
        this.addChild(myContainer);

        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEveryFrame);
    }

    private function onEveryFrame(ev:Event):void
    {
        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
        myContainer.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - myContainer.width / 2;
        myContainer.y = 40;
    }

    private function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
    {
        var lastElement = myArray.length - 1;
        trace(lastElement);
        this.removeChild(myArray[lastElement]);
        myArray.pop();
    }
}
```

}

if i try  just to add the cards on the stage directly (not like here -> in the Container) it does what i want from it (it removes the last card), but then i cant figure out how to center the whole array of cards on the stage.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `onClick` method:

```
myContainer.removeChild(myArray[lastElement]);
```

You are adding the cards to myContainer, so you remove them from myContainer as well.

Answer (score 1):

You add cards to myContainer element, but remove them from this element, but this didn't consist from this objects.

Your code:

```
private function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var lastElement = myArray.length - 1;
            trace(lastElement);
            this.removeChild(myArray[lastElement]);
            myArray.pop();
        }
```

Replace on this:

```
private function onClick(evt:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var lastElement = myArray.length - 1;
            trace(lastElement);
            myContainer.removeChild(myArray[lastElement]);
            myArray.pop();
        }
```